# How to export data from this website to excel?

Tags: web-scraping

There is this list of ~5000 companies on https://www.inc.com/inc5000/2022.

I want to extract this data and put it into excel. Even better would be if I could pull just the software companies' data (check the "Software" filter in "Industries").

But I can also just do that in excel so works for me either way. I just need help getting the data from the website into Excel right now. I've tried pasting the link directly into excel without success.

I've tried using R, with code I found on a [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/datasets/comments/p71caa/how_can_i_export_this_inc_5000_dataset_as_an/) but the resulting CSV file only had 98 rows in it instead of the ~5000 it should've been. I'm not a programmer so, really dumb things down for me.

I only managed to run the .R file I got from Reddit after downloading R, Rstudio, then making adjustments in [this code](https://gist.github.com/MattSandy/a5e4bfdd2da9c03628d10495b1511b94)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)
df <- "https://api.inc.com/rest/i5list/2021" %>%
  fromJSON() %>% 
  .$companies %>% 
  bind_rows() %>%
  unnest(article) %>%
  select(-editorsPick) %>%
  write_csv("inc.csv")
```

so that it's pulling from the 2022 version of the inc 5000 lists instead of the 2021 version.

Comment: Can you pull the data from their API (https://api.inc.com/rest/i5list/2022/) into Excel and filter by Industry "Software" there? I could not find any API documentation online.

Comment: I could get the data with `curl https://api.inc.com/rest/i5list/2022 > companies_2022.txt`. I found 592 software companies in the new txt file.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is write a simple script the easiest thing would probably be to just use python and the requests library.

```
import requests

data = requests.get("https://api.inc.com/rest/i5list/2022",).json()
with open("data.csv", "w+") as f:
    f.write("Rank,Company,Growth,Industry,State,City\n")
    for i in data["companies"]:
        f.write("{},{},{}%,{},{},{}\n".format(i["rank"], i["company"], i["growth"], i["industry"], i["state_s"], i["city"]))
```

The code above should work for you it writes all the companies to a csv file (which you can open with excel). There are more properties in the json response, however what I've included is what is shown on the frontend website.